# How to replace sysvinit with systemd in a Debian based distribution?

Tags: systemd, sysvinit

I've been using systemd for a while in my Debian installation, just that to make it possible I had to add a boot parameter to the `/etc/default/grub` file to make it work, which is added to Ubuntu boot parameters. Ubuntu doesn't have installed systemd yet so I have to remove it or the boot can fail. So, I'm looking for a way to replace sysvinit with systemd and remove the boot parameter, how would I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was easier than I thought, just installing the `systemd-sysv` package made all the necessary changes:

> **Breaks: sysvinit-core**
>    Description-en: system and service manager - SysV links
>    systemd is a replacement for sysvinit.  It is dependency-based and
>    able to read the LSB init script headers in addition to parsing rcN.d
>    links as hints.
>
> It also provides process supervision using cgroups and the ability to
>    not only depend on other init script being started, but also
>    availability of a given mount point or dbus service.
>
> **This package provides the manual pages and links needed for systemd
>    to replace sysvinit.**

It removed sysvinit binary (removing sysvinit-core) and replaced `/sbin/init` with a symlink to `/lib/systemd/systemd`

Answer (score 2):

Just note that `systemd` on Debian will run mostly in SysVinit compatibility mode (i.e., running the legacy scripts). It will take perhaps a release cycle to get all sorted out. Most of the unit files are being developed upstream or can be pilfered from distributions that are further along the migration (they aren't ridiculously distribution specific, as SysVinit scripts are).

Comment: I do not think this answers my question and seems more like a comment to either my answer or question.

Comment: @Braiam In the context of the information already on the page, this is a valuable addition--more so than just a comment. +1.

Comment: It seems like a valuable comment about how Debian (or any other distro) will go about integrating systemd overall, but I don't think it really answers the particular question, which is clearly about how an individual might switch to it _on their own system_.